# Connected component in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ be the set of infinite sequences of real numbers.  I'm trying to find the connected component containing $x=(0,1,2,3,\cdots)$, in the uniform topology.   I believe that $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ isn't even connected because I think $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ and its complement disconnect the space.  But I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I have a write-up here: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2001;task=show_msg;msg=0287

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $B$ be the set of bounded sequences in $\Bbb R^\omega$. Show that $B$ is the component of the zero sequence; you can do this by showing that it’s clopen and path-connected. Then consider $x+B$.

Comment: I'm having difficulty showing its path-connected, my first thought was a straight line homotopy but this isn't continuous in this topology, necessarily.  Because if it were then the whole space would be (path) connected, but it is not.  Otherwise, I understand the argument.

Comment: @Squirtle: If by *straight line homotopy* you mean what Mariano suggested, it is continuous within $B$.

Comment: Mariano?  I don't see any such comment.

Comment: @Squirtle: Not a comment, but rather his answer.